# Error al sumar N elementos con Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Tengo un problema al sumar todos los totales, logra sumar los totales de cada producto y un total final pero al momento de editar un precio o cantidad esta se suma al total final y no es editada correctamente.

Código:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<title>Prueba de concepto de agregado y cálculo dinámico.</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="css/base.css" />
<style type="text/css">
#contenedor {
 width: 90%;
 margin: auto;
}
#tabla {
 width: 100%;
 margin: auto;
 border: 1px solid #a1a1a1;
}
#tabla thead tr {
 background-color: #afafaf;
}
#tabla thead tr th, #tabla tbody tr td {
 border: 1px solid #a1a1a1;
 padding: 3px;
}
#tabla tbody tr td input {
 padding: 3px;
 border: 1px solid #717171;
}
#total {
 font-size: 1.1em;
 font-weight: bold;
}
</style>
<script type="text/javascript">
function AddItem() {
 var tbody = null;
 var tabla = document.getElementById("tabla");
 var nodes = tabla.childNodes;
 for (var x = 0; x<nodes.length;x++) {
  if (nodes[x].nodeName == 'TBODY') {
   tbody = nodes[x];
   break;
  }
 }
 if (tbody != null) {
  var tr = document.createElement('tr');
  tr.innerHTML = '<td><input type="text" name="item[]"/></td><td><input type="text" name="cantidad[]" onChange="Calcular(this);" value="1" /></td><td><input type="text" name="precunit[]" onChange="Calcular(this);" value="0"/></td><td><input type="text" name="totalitem[]" readonly /></td>';
  tbody.appendChild(tr);
 }
}

function Calcular(ele) {
 var cantidad = 0, precunit = 0, totalitem = 0;
 var tr = ele.parentNode.parentNode;
 var nodes = tr.childNodes;
 for (var x = 0; x<nodes.length;x++) {
  if (nodes[x].firstChild.name == 'cantidad[]') {
   cantidad = parseFloat(nodes[x].firstChild.value,10);
  }
  if (nodes[x].firstChild.name == 'precunit[]') {
   precunit = parseFloat(nodes[x].firstChild.value,10);
  }
  if (nodes[x].firstChild.name == 'totalitem[]') {
   totalitem = parseFloat((precunit*cantidad),10);
   nodes[x].firstChild.value = totalitem;
  }
 }
 var total = document.getElementById("total");
 if (total.innerHTML == 'NaN') {
  total.innerHTML = 0;
 }
 total.innerHTML = parseFloat(total.innerHTML)+totalitem;
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<form name="frmitems" id="frmitems" action="recibe221.php" method="POST">
 <div id="contenedor">
  <table id="tabla">
   <thead>
    <tr>
     <th>Item</th>
     <th>Cantidad</th>
     <th>Precio Unitario</th>
     <th>Total</th>
    </tr>
   </thead>
   <tbody>
    
   </tbody>
   <tfoot>
    <tr>
     <td>Total</td>
     <td>&nbsp;</td>
     <td>&nbsp;</td>
     <td><span id="total">0</span></td>
    </tr>
   </tfoot>
  </table>
  <button type="button" onClick="AddItem();">Agregar item.</button>
 </div>
 <input type="submit" value="Enviar" />
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

El detalle lo tienes al momento de llamar la función `Calcular`; el valor antes de la modificación no se esta restando a **Total** (al final de la tabla) solo estas sumando el nuevo valor (de la modificación).

Te sugiero realices el cálculo de todos elementos existentes (practicamente recorrer todos los elemento y obtener el `totalitem` e ir sumándolo, o agregar un nuevo parámetro a 'Calcular' en el cual pases el valor que tenia antes de su modificación para restarlo para al final hacer algo como:

```
total.innerHTML = parseFloat(total.innerHTML)+totalitem-valorAntesModificar;
```

Realice lo siguiente para que agregues a tu código:

Modificación a función `AddItem`:

```
function AddItem() {
    var tbody = null;
    var tabla = document.getElementById("tabla");
    var nodes = tabla.childNodes;
    for (var x = 0; x<nodes.length;x++) {
        if (nodes[x].nodeName == 'TBODY') {
            tbody = nodes[x];
            break;
        }
    }
    if (tbody != null) {
        var tr = document.createElement('tr');
        tr.innerHTML = '<td><input type="text" name="item[]"/></td><td><input type="text" name="cantidad[]" onChange="Calcular(this);" value="1" /></td><td><input type="text" name="precunit[]" onChange="Calcular(this);" value="0"/></td><td><input type="text" name="totalitem[]" readonly /></td>';
        /// agrege la siguiente (por la estructura que usaste; aquí guardo el valor anterior
        tr.innerHTML+='<td style="display:none"><input type="text" name="totalitemold[]" value="0" /></td>';
        tbody.appendChild(tr);
    }
}
```

Realice camnbios a `Calcular`:

```
  function Calcular(ele) {
    var cantidad = 0, precunit = 0, totalitem = 0;
    var tr = ele.parentNode.parentNode;
    var nodes = tr.childNodes;
    // Inicio: Lo tenias casi al final
    var total = document.getElementById("total");
      if (total.innerHTML == 'NaN') {
          total.innerHTML = 0;
      }
    // Fin: Lo tenias casi al final

    for (var x = 0; x<nodes.length;x++) {
        if (nodes[x].firstChild.name == 'cantidad[]') {
            cantidad = parseFloat(nodes[x].firstChild.value,10);
        }
        if (nodes[x].firstChild.name == 'precunit[]') {
            precunit = parseFloat(nodes[x].firstChild.value,10);
        }
        if (nodes[x].firstChild.name == 'totalitem[]') {
            totalitem = parseFloat((precunit*cantidad),10);
            nodes[x].firstChild.value = totalitem;
        }
        if (nodes[x].firstChild.name == 'totalitemold[]') {
            total.innerHTML = parseFloat(total.innerHTML)-parseFloat(nodes[x].firstChild.value,10); // Restamos lo anterior
            nodes[x].firstChild.value=totalitem; //  Asumiendo no hay falla se coloca el nuevo valor de "if (nodes[x].firstChild.name == 'totalitem[]')", el cual será el "valor antes de modificar"
        }
    }

    total.innerHTML = parseFloat(total.innerHTML)+totalitem;
}
```

**Notas:**

1. Por la estructura que manejas, agrege un TD el cual lo puse oculto; verifica no afecte al presentarse; en caso que sí agrega en `<thead>` un `<td style="display:none"></td>` luego de `<th>Total</th>` y colocale .

Comment: Muchas gracias! :D

Comment: @JhosselinGiménez sí, con gusto. Quedo en espera.

Comment: @JhosselinGiménez ya estoy revisándolo, te comento tan pronto concluya.

Comment: @JhosselinGiménez ¿como te puedo hacer llegar los cambios?

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/56213/discussion-between-roberto-leon-oramas-and-jhosselin-gimenez).

Comment: @JhosselinGiménez Por favor formula una nueva pregunta si hay alguna cuestión extra a preguntar. El sitio no es para una interacción entre 2 usuarios. [es.so] es un sitio de preguntas y respuestas que busca generar contenido del que todos puedan beneficiarse.